# history.push on form submit

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a newbie to react and I'm trying to route on a different set of components after a form (in my case a search bar) has been submitted (using onSubmit event). I have my search component wrapped in withRouter and have the history deconstructed. I've tried using onClick and the push does trigger, but does not seem to do anything with onSubmit. Hoping for your advise.

Thank you

Search component

```
const SearchAppBar = (props) => {
  const {
    history,
    onPlatformDrop,
    onPlatformChange,
    onPriceRangeDrop,
    clearPriceRange,
    searchQuery,
    setSearchQuery,
    clearGenre,
    onDropDownChange,
  } = props;
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Search
        sx={{
          width: { xs: "85vw", md: "50vw", lg: "30vw" },
          margin: "auto",
          marginBottom: "20px",
        }}
      >
        <form action="/" method="get" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <StyledInputBase
            defaultValue={searchQuery}
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder="Search All Games…"
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
            type="search"
            name="s"
            id="site-search"
          />

          <SearchIconWrapper>
            <IconButton
              type="submit"
              onSubmit={(e) => {
                history.push("/find");
                clearGenre();
                clearPriceRange();
                onPlatformChange("");
                onPlatformDrop("All Platforms");
                onPriceRangeDrop("All Price Range");
                onDropDownChange("All Genres");
                setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <SearchIcon style={{ color: "#55597d" }} />
            </IconButton>
          </SearchIconWrapper>
        </form>
      </Search>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default withRouter(SearchAppBar);
```

Then on my App, i have something like this:

```
<Route
  path="/find"
  exact
  render={(props) => (
    <div>
      <Search
        onPlatformChange={onPlatformChange}
        onPlatformDrop={onPlatformDrop}
        clearPriceRange={clearPriceRange}
        onPriceRangeDrop={onPriceRangeDrop}
        searchQuery={searchQuery}
        setSearchQuery={setSearchQuery}
        clearGenre={clearGenre}
        onDropDownChange={onDropDownChange}
      />
    </div>
  )}
/>;
```

Comment: why don't you use `useHistory` hook instead of using `withRouter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onSubmit` handler should be on the `form` element, not the button submitting the form. Remove the form action and method. You will also need to prevent the default form action from occurring, if you don't then the form is submitted and the page reloads.

```
<form
  style={{ display: "flex" }}
  onSubmit={(e) => {       // handles form submission
    e.preventDefault();    // prevents default form action
    history.push("/find"); // navigate
    ...
    setSearchQuery(e.target.s.value); // <-- access field value
  }}
>
  <StyledInputBase
    ...
    name="s" // <-- access in submit handler
    ...
  />
  <SearchIconWrapper>
    <IconButton type="submit">
      <SearchIcon style={{ color: "#55597d" }} />
    </IconButton>
  </SearchIconWrapper>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thank you for the response. However, setSearchQuery(e.target.value) does not seem to capture my input value anymore when I put it in the form element. Gives me undefined.

Comment: @Forged What value was it getting previously? I guess there's only the `StyledInputBase` component? You can access the form fields from the `onSubmit` object. I'll update.

Comment: Yes, only the value from my StyledInputBase. Thanks a lot if you can show me how its properly done!